# How I can Highlight the code line in page with React.js in file .jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I try some library but nothing done the job.

I try:

```
  react-syntax-highlighter
```

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter) 
after install and following the documentation the module always not found in my file .jsx. The dependency is in my package.json but the module is not found. (paranormal activity)

```
   react-highlight
```

(https://github.com/akiran/react-highlight)
the module is found but don't work, the coloration of the line stay always dark

```
  react-highlight
```

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight)

... and more

If someone have any solution for color my text ^^ 
[image]

the code is :

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import Highlight from "react-highlight";

    export const ButtonLib = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <pre>
                    <code id="foo" ref={myRef}>
                        <Highlight language="javascript">
                            import React from "react";
                            import { Button } from "Antd";

                            export const Button = () => {
                                return (
                                     <span>
                                         <Button size="small">Small</Button>
                                         <Button size="medium">Medium</Button>
                                         <Button size="large">Large</Button>
                                         <JumboButton>Jumbo</JumboButton>                                                                                                                                                     <AuthenticationButton>Authentication</AuthenticationButton>
                                     </span>
                                 );
                            }
                        </Highlight>
                    </code>
              </pre>
         </div>
       );
};
```

Comment: You should probably need to import the CSS theme file

Comment: No, in the example there is not import of style but I put update the post with the code

Comment: https://medium.com/get-it-working/get-prismjs-working-in-react-a6d989e59290

I have a gatsby site and I use prism.js this to highlight, this should work in plain react.

Comment: The coloration with Prism is better than react-highlight, but may be I use wrong react-highlight ^^

Answer (score 1):

As Per the official documentation of `react-highlight`

[Visit Adding Styles In React Highlight](https://github.com/akiran/react-highlight#adding-styles)

From my perspective Adding a import statement in your component should work .

```
import 'highlight.js/styles/github.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

> `react-highlight` only *converts* your code in HTML with CSS classes. Without any CSS definitions, you won't see much of a difference.

- You have to **include CSS/styles** from `highlight.js`, which are already included in the node package, so you can import one of them right away.
- There is **no need to add highlight.js** as a dependency.

Instead of

```js
import 'highlight.js/styles/github.css'
```

you could write:

```js
import 'react-highlight.js/node_modules/highlight.js/styles/github.css'
```

You can preview all styles at https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/.